# how to detect Mac retina display in python?

Tags: python, wxpython, retina-display

I read that wx python 2.9.5+ supports wx.Window.GetContentScaleFactor (see http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Window.html#Window.GetContentScaleFactor), and will return 2.0 for a retina display.

I have a class that inherits from wx.Frame, which inherits from wx.Window. But GetContentScaleFactor is not there. Apparently there was a bug like this in wxPerl (https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=96136) -- something similar in wxPython?

Any ideas?

Edit: more info:

```
>>> wx.version()
'3.0.0.0 osx-cocoa (classic)'
>>> isinstance(wx.Frame(None), wx.Window)
True
>>> 'GetContentScaleFactor' in dir(wx.Frame(None))
False
```

Comment: I could be totally off track since I haven't used wx in years, but the [class hierarchy](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Frame.html#class-hierarchy-class-hierarchy) says that Frame inherits from Window, so your frame should just have the GetContentScaleFactor method.

Comment: thanks Andrew--I already tried that, also looked at .GetHandle() a bit

Comment: Do you really need to know specifically that you are running on a Mac retina display, or do you really care if you're running on any high resolution display?

Comment: Yes, any high-res display, actually. Hopefully Apple's ".@2x" naming convention will stick as a standard and be widely adopted (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in wxPython Phoenix:
3.0.2.dev77483
wx.Window.GetContentScaleFactor

As Phoenix does some of the wrapping work automagically I would guess that Robin didn't get around to do this for Classic.

Maybe do a ticket on http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ or post to wxPython-dev.